# Dual monitor display 12.04?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, proprietary, twinview, dualhead

I have 2 beautiful 27" ASUS monitors. I started trying out Ubuntu 12.04 and now only one works and thats VGA.

Any help here cause I'm stumped. I have a *BFG Tech Nivida Geforce 8800 GT 512MB* and I'm trying to fix this.

I get this error when I try to configure the xorg file:

```
Failed to set MetaMode (1) 'DFP-0: 1280x1024 @1280x1024 +0+0, DFP-1: 1280x1024 @1280x1024 +1280+0' (Mode 2560x1024, id: 50) on X screen 0.
```

This is the xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@allspice)  Fri Mar 30 15:25:24 UTC 2012


Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Mouse Remap"
        MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE247"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE247"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1500"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1500"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "1"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0, DFP-1: 1280x1024 +1280+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0, DFP-1: 1280x1024 +1280+0; DFP-1: 1280x1024_60 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: What driver are you using the default one or the proprietary one? At least twinview with the proprietary driver should work. Please do not use VGA if possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be easy to get it working, if you provide more information.

Comment: I Got it Up with the Nvidia settings Menue and now the other screen is white ? so idk what i should do to get this working .. 
im using dvi input right now. i used the On board video card to get the drivers. im getting this error




I

Comment: You have now two questions open for probably the same issue, please use only one. Preferably the other one.