# How to setup dual-screen monitors in xorg.conf using Nvidia TwinView?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, proprietary, twinview, dualhead

I have the following `xorg.conf` file, but TwinView is not working for me when using 2 monitors. Please help me get things sorted out.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@allspice)  Fri Mar 30 15:25:24 UTC 2012


Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE247"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE247"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1500"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1500"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "1"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0, DFP-1: 1280x1024 +1280+0"
# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0, DFP-1: 1280x1024 +1280+0; DFP-1: 1280x1024_60 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Here are my computers specifications:

```
Computer:
Processor           : 2x Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
Memory              : 3339MB (2889MB used)
Operating System    : Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
User Name           : chikaru (Mrmagu)
Date/Time           : Sat 22 Sep 2012 12:18:13 PM EDT

Display:
Resolution          : 2560x1024 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : Quadro FX 1500/PCIe/SSE2
X11 Vendor          : The X.Org Foundation

Multimedia:
Audio Adapter       : SB-XFi - Creative X-Fi
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
Audio Adapter       : USB-Audio - Producer USB

Input Devices:
Sleep Button
Power Button
Razer Razer Lycosa
Razer Razer Lycosa
Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse
HDA Intel Front Headphone
HDA Intel Rear Mic
HDA Intel Line
HDA Intel Line-Out Front

Printers:
No printers found

SCSI Disks:
Optiarc DVD RW AD-5200A
BENQ DVD LS DW1655
ATA ST380817AS
ATA MDT MD1600JS-00S
ATA Hitachi HDS72303
ATA ST3320820AS
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/191503/dual-monitor-display-12-04

Comment: The setup is the same as for the other question I guess (Nvidia Geforce 8800 GT, two ASUS monitors)? What exactly is the model number of the monitors? Are both monitors now connected via DVI/HDMI/DisplayPort to the Nvidia card? What processor do you have? On Intel Core i3/i5/i7 Generation 2000/3000 that would also be worth a try.

Comment: Okay you have a Pentium 4 and so onboard graphics won't be better in that case. Could you please give me the model number of your monitors?

Answer (score 3):

Following configuration has been working for me with two Dell U2312HM, back when I was using Nvidia TwinView, but don't just do copy & paste.

```bash
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildd@yellow)  Fri Apr  9 11:51:21 UTC 2010

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Layout0"
        Screen  0       "Screen0" 0 0
#       InputDevice     "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
#       InputDevice     "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        Option          "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        # generated from default
        Identifier      "Mouse0"
        Driver          "mouse"
        Option          "Protocol" "auto"
        Option          "Device" "/dev/psaux"
        Option          "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
        Option          "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        # generated from default
        Identifier      "Keyboard0"
        Driver          "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
        Identifier      "Monitor0"
        VendorName      "DELL"
        ModelName       "DELL U2312HM"
        HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
        VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
        Option          "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Device0"
        Driver          "nvidia"
        VendorName      "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName       "GeForce 210"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen0"
        Device          "Device0"
        Monitor         "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option          "TwinView" "1"
        Option          "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
        Option          "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0, DFP-1: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0"
        SubSection      "Display"
                Depth       24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```