# NVIDIA dual monitor configuration unsupported after rebooting

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with the Ubuntu supplied NVIDIA drivers for my Geforce 9800 GT. When I go into nvidia-settings and enable my 2nd monitor and click apply, it turns on and works great. Then I save the configuration to the xorg.conf file. However, when I reboot I get a message saying that the configuration is not supported and that I have to run in low graphics mode. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You can't do it that way, because `nvidia-settings` does not generate a proper `xorg.conf` file you have to do it by hand as far as I know. I have posted my old configuration over there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191550/how-to-setup-dual-screen-monitors-in-xorg-conf-using-nvidia-twinview/191588#191588 may be that gets you started.